# Multiple remote_form_for on the same page causes duplicate ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a rails app that displays a list of items called modules.  I'm iterating over these, rendering a partial for each one that includes a remote_form_for call.

This all works, but fails HTML validation because my form text fields all have the same id.

Is there a :prefix option  on the form (or something else) I can use to get around this?

Update:
(some code)

```
    //_module_form.html.erb
    <% remote_form_for app_module do |f| %>
         <%= f.label :name %>
         <%= f.text_field :name %>
         <%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
    <%end %>

    //parent page
    <% @thing.modules.each do |app_module| %>
       <%= render :partial => "module_form", :locals => { :app_module => app_module } %>
    <% end %>
```

So if I have more than 1 item in the collection, I render the identical form on the same page, and the form id and textbox id are duplicated.

I can customize the form id pretty easily, but what about the text_box, since the controller is looking for specific named controls?

Comment: We need some code to understand

Comment: Can you add your code to question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `:index => object.id` to the options hash when creating your form. This should generate ids in the form of `object_id_attribute` without interfering with the controller.

**Edit**

The documentation regarding `:index` is is ambiguously misleading. `:index` does have an effect on the form submission. The solution is to specify the `:id` attribute for each field. This will change the `id` property, leaving `name` unharmed (which is what counts for the submission).

Here is the code I use in a generic helper for generating these fields:

```
def create_field( f, field_type, object, field_name )
    field_id = "#{object.class.name.downcase}_#{object.id.to_s}_#{field_name.to_s}"
    f.send( field_type, field_name, :id => field_id )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over them with `collection.each_with_index do |item, i|` then on the render partial pass in a local variable:

```
render :partial => "some_partial", :locals => {:form_id => "form_id_#{i}"}
```

Then in the partial you can access `<%= form_id %>`

That would be one way to do it.

I'm assuming in the remote_form_for you can pass in :id => form_id or :html_options => {:id => form_id}

Looks like you can, see:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001649

Comment: that addresses my duplicate form id, but what about the textbox ids?

Comment: You can set the id in the text_field in a similar fashion, by passing in :id to the text_field helper. The name attribute on the input fields should be taken care of by the form helper anyway. Why not do use something like :id => "app_module_#{app_module.id}_name"

Comment: If I do that, my controller no longer functions correctly, because it doesn't understand the params that are posted in.

Comment: You will need to make sure the controller knows how to deal with the params being posted in. You can also set the :name on the text boxes too in the same way as the id. So you could ask which module is it and make sure the name is set accordingly.